# Use AWS CLI to sync files on Windows instance to AWS S3 bucket and delete older files (without storage gateway or FSx)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

As my title says I'm looking for a way to use the AWS CLI commands (or other free/cheap methods) to sync local backups on my Windows machine to S3 and then also delete the oldest file or files older than a set number of days from S3.

We can't afford storage gateway solution, and due to account security cannot use FSx.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to achieve this;

1. Install AWS CLI utility in Windows
2. Configure AWS CLI with access and secret keys
3. Create a Bucket in S3
4. Use S3 sync command to upload backups to S3
5. Set lifecycle policy on S3 bucket to remove files from S3 after
   certain time

Ref:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-windows.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev-retired/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html

Comment: I ended up using S3 mv command as I didn't need local copies to remain and didn't want to run a windows task to delete the files later.